# managing session after closing the app without log out in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How to maintain session in Android. For example in my app, the user can log in by using normal log in or Facebook log in. And after using the app the user can close the app by logging out the session or the user can simply close the app without log out. So that the user can enter in to the home screen with out log in for the next time.

When my app is closed with out logging out the session and opened after a period of two days, the user session is lost and my app gets crashed. When it is logged out properly and then opened, app works fine. How to manage session when closed without log out?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can use shared preferences for storing user information so that next time it will not ask log in. And your next problem handling sessions. So on your server side you are destroying session after particular times period. what you can do use time stamp for that. In my case i am using it like this: My server destroying session after 3 hours automatically. So when user log in to my application i save time stamp for that. Next time I am checking time stamp whether it is expired or not. If it is expired then first call for log in in background on behalf of user. So that server will create new session for user.

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain it in `SharedPreferences`.Look [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for your reference.

For example, to save username, password and session ID, you can:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
 edit.putString("User Name", username);
 edit.putString("Password", password);
 edit.putInt("Session ID", session_id);
 edit.commit();
```

and get them

```
 SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
 username = pref.getString("User Name", "");
 password = pref.getString("Password", "");
 session_id = pref.getInt("Session ID", 0);
```